# Retrieve simple XML rest web service data using jersey

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I tried a simple example to make rest web service using jersey in eclipse IDE. This web service assumed to return a simple information in XML format for an object as shown in the class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("aliens")
public class AlienResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

    public Alien getAlien() {
        System.out.println("getAlien called successfully!!!!");

        Alien a1 = new Alien();
        a1.setName("Ahmed");
        a1.setPoints(90);
        return a1;
    }

}
```

I am using Tomcat web server 9. I tried to use different versions of jersey without any errors seen in the console but I still got an internal server error 500.

*this is my pom.xml file*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ali</groupId>
    <artifactId>try2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>try2</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>try2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**how to solve this problem?**

> note: **It works perfectly with JSON format.**

*A model class:*

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {
    private String name;
    private int points;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to view the data with json format only

Comment: @Amjad thanks it works with the json format. but I am wondering what cause the problem for showing results in XML format